# Triples that exist in the database not returned with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, marklogic, triplestore, triples

I have triples ingested in a collection named (**collec_1**), and then I inserted triples using `rdf-insert` where those triples added to the same collection (**collec_1**).

When I use the `estimate` function to count how many doc in the collection I see that the triples exist, but when I query using SPARQL I see fewer triples returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM <collec_1>
WHERE 
{ ?s ?p ?o}
```

**NOTE** : I have increased the number of forests before ingesting triples to accommodate with the changes. Is this the cause? The triples may stored in different forests!

Comment: The number of forests your database shouldn't matter. It is more likely an issue with permissions. May want to verify what the permissions are on those records, and see if you get similar results when running with a user with `admin` role?

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have an admin role but still could not get them in the results. @MadsHansen